# How to display string formatters as plain text in Java?

Tags: java, string, escaping, string-formatting

I have a string in Java that contains special characters like \n and \t which are interpreted as control characters and produce new lines and tabs when displayed. I want to display these special characters as plain text, for example, to display "\n" as \n and not as a new line. The string may also contain single or double quotation marks(')(") to be concise it can contain any possible character.

```
String text = "Hello\nWorld!";
text = text.replace("\\", "\\\\");
text = text.replace("\n", "\\n");
System.out.println(text);
```

Is there a way to achieve this in Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an one way using streams.

```
String text = "He\f\bllo\nWor\rld!";
text = translate(text);
```

prints

```
He\f\bllo\nWor\rld!
```

- this splits the string and then replaces the proper control character with its escaped outerpart.

```
private static Map<Character, String> map = Map.of('\t', "\\t", '\b', "\\b", '\n',
        "\\n", '\f', "\\f", '\\', "\\\'", '"', "\\\"", '\r', "\\r");
public static String translate(String text) {
    return text.chars()
            .mapToObj(ch -> map.getOrDefault((char)ch, Character.toString(ch)))
            .collect(Collectors.joining());    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Apache commons has a library for what you seem to be looking for: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/text/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeJava(java.lang.String)

If you can't use Maven/Gradle then you'll most likely have to resort to rolling your own by escaping all special characters with a backslash i.e. something like:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String text = "Hello\nWorld!";
    String escapedText = escapeSpecialChars(text);
    System.out.println(escapedText);
}

private static String escapeSpecialChars(String text) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (char c : text.toCharArray()) {
        switch (c) {
            case '\\' -> sb.append("\\\\");
            case '\n' -> sb.append("\\n");
            case '\t' -> sb.append("\\t");
            case '\'' -> sb.append("\\'");
            case '\"' -> sb.append("\\\"");
            default -> sb.append(c);
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```